# Does PHP have short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: php, if-statement, short-circuiting

Given the following code:

```
if (is_valid($string) && up_to_length($string) && file_exists($file)) 
{
    ......
}
```

If `is_valid($string)` returns `false`, does the php interpreter still check later conditions, like `up_to_length($string)`?
If so, then why does it do extra work when it doesn't have to?

Comment: Some reading to go along with all these answers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: This is referring to the topic of short-circuit evaluation, and different languages handle it differently.

Comment: @AJ: Honestly, I'm yet to see a (serious/widely used) programming language that doesn't have short-circuit evaluation for logical and and logical or. Do you have an example?

Comment: @delnan - I think what you meant was "Most widely-used programming languages don't implement any **eager** operators."

Comment: @AJ: The operator `+` is perfectly eager in countless languages, and so is binary and/or. No, I'm sure I'm asking about languages where logical and and logical or don't short-circuit.

Comment: @delnan - VB and Fortran come to mind...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Yes, the PHP interpreter is "lazy", meaning it will do the minimum number of comparisons possible to evaluate conditions.

If you want to verify that, try this:

```
function saySomething()
{
    echo 'hi!';
    return true;
}

if (false && saySomething())
{
    echo 'statement evaluated to true';
}
```

Comment: Short circuit evaluation != lazy.

Comment: @delnan: This is an example of lazy evaluation. See http://books.google.com/books?id=vogP3P2L4tgC&pg=PA367#v=onepage&q=lazy&f=false.

Comment: A *tiny* example, and an arguable one (in the same vein, one could call if statements an example of lazy evaluation). Lazy evaluation is much more general - it applies to *every* expression *everywhere* (although you can usually force evaluation without using the value). That book excerpt gets this right.

Comment: Do you know of any ways to disable this behaviour ?

Comment: @RaduMurzea: short circuiting is not something I expect to be toggled as it can have adverse consequences to an entire program and imported libraries.  consider the situation where you check if a variable is set before reading it `if (isset($var['index']) && $var['index'] === "something")`.  if you need to evaluate each condition in a boolean expression, then evaluate and save them before the if statement, then check the results in the if condition.

Comment: Actual answer to OP question is "Yes", not "No."  Yes it short circuits, no it does not check later conditions....

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @kevinc. The question has been edited since I posted my answer so I had to update my answer.

Answer (score 11):

[Bitwise operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) are `&` and `|`.
They always evaluate both operands.

[Logical operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) are `AND`, `OR`, `&&`, and `||`.

- All four operators only evaluate the right side if they need to.
- `AND` and `OR` have lower precedence than `&&` and `||`. See example below.

From the PHP manual:

```
// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f before the "or" operation occurs
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

In this example, `e` will be `true` and `f` will be `false`.

Comment: *"AND and OR always evaluate both operands."* -- this is not true. They only have lower precedence than `&&` and `||` but other than that they have the same semantic as `&&` and `||`.

Comment: will add good notice from manual: "Note that PHP's boolean operators *always* return a boolean value... as opposed to other languages that return the value of the last evaluated expression."

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it does. Here's a little trick that relies on short-circuit evaluation. Sometimes you might have a small if statement that you'd prefer to write as a ternary, e.g.:

```
    if ($confirmed) {
        $answer = 'Yes';
    } else {
        $answer = 'No';
    }
```

Can be re-written as:

```
   $answer = $confirmed ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

But then what if the yes block also required some function to be run?

```
    if ($confirmed) {
        do_something();

        $answer = 'Yes';
    } else {
        $answer = 'No';
    }
```

Well, rewriting as ternary is still possible, because of short-circuit evaluation:

```
    $answer = $confirmed && (do_something() || true) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

In this case the expression (do_something() || true) does nothing to alter the overall outcome of the ternary, but ensures that the ternary condition stays `true`, ignoring the return value of `do_something()`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my research now, PHP doesn't seem to have the same `&&` short circuit operator as JavaScript.

I ran this test:

```
$one = true;

$two = 'Cabbage';

$test = $one && $two;

echo $test;
```

and PHP 7.0.8 returned `1`, not `Cabbage`.

Comment: I think `&&` causes php to cast everything into a boolean, so that `$two` is cast to `true`, and then echoed as `1`.  You would need `true||(echo 'no short circuit')` to test that (or something like it).

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't anymore check the other conditions if the first condition isn't satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I've create my own short-circuit evaluation logic, unfortunately it's nothing like javascripts quick syntax, but perhaps this is a solution you might find useful:

```
$short_circuit_isset = function($var, $default_value = NULL) {
    return  (isset($var)) ? : $default_value;
};

$return_title = $short_circuit_isset( $_GET['returntitle'], 'God');

// Should return type 'String' value 'God', if get param is not set
```

I can not recall where I got the following logic from, but if you do the following;

```
(isset($var)) ? : $default_value;
```

You can skip having to write the true condition variable again, after the question mark, e.g:

```
(isset($super_long_var_name)) ? $super_long_var_name : $default_value;
```

**As very important observation**, when using the *Ternary Operator* this way, you'll notice that if a comparison is made it will just pass the value of that comparison, since there isn't just a single variable. E.g:

```
$num = 1;
$num2 = 2;
var_dump( ($num < $num2) ? : 'oh snap' );
// outputs bool 'true'
```

Comment: That logic with the `?:` works just like JavaScript/Perl's `||`.

Comment: Not quite trysys -- the left hand argument seems to be scanned for an expression which is returned if it is true -- regardless of a function around it.  (Ex: isset($var) ?: '1' produces $var if the first expression in true).

Answer (score 0):

In this example I expected according to the precedence rules at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php for $a to be equivalent to $b. However, because of short circuiting, $a is true and $b is false.

```
<?php

 $a = 1 || 0 && 0;
 $b = (1 || 0) && 0;
```

Answer (score -6):

My choice: **do not** trust Short Circuit evaluation in PHP...

```
function saySomething()
{
    print ('hi!');
    return true;
}

if (1 || saySomething())
{
    print('statement evaluated to true');
}
```

The second part in the condition **1 || saySomething()** is irrelevant, because this will always return true. Unfortunately **saySomething()** is evaluated & executed.

Maybe I'm misunderstood the exact logic of short-circuiting expressions, but this doesn't look like **"it will do the minimum number of comparisons possible"** to me.

Moreover, it's not only a performance concern, if you do assignments inside comparisons or if you do something that makes a difference, other than just comparing stuff, you could end with different results.

Anyway... be careful.

Comment: That might be the reason for whether it's about short-circuit evaluation or eagerness.  It stops as soon as it knows the result will be false.

Comment: Actually I just ran your code and it didn't execute saySomething().  PHP 5.3.13

Comment: +1 to grantwparks, saySomething() does *not* get executed.  PHP properly short circuits.  I've been writing this sort of code in PHP for the better part of a decade now, I don't recall ever getting hung up on this issue.  Occasionally I write more verbose code if I feel a little extra clarity is important, but usually a code comment is enough to cover that concern.

Comment: You are right. I ran my own test again and function saySomething() never gets executed. I don't know what could went wrong in my first tests. Sorry :(

Comment: Its a proof that php behaviour is consistent.  if first value in OR condition is true its obvious if is true it does not process rest of statements its consistent with short circuit behaviour.

Comment: Rewording the second print statement reveals the answer more clearly...
```
function saySomething()
{
    print ('hi!');
    return true;
}

if (1 || saySomething())
{
    print('goodbye');
}
```

Answer (score -8):

**Side note:** If you want to avoid the lazy check and run every part of the condition, in that case you need to use the logical AND like this:

```
if (condition1 & condition2) {
 echo "both true";
}
else {
 echo "one or both false";
}
```

This is useful when you need for example call two functions even if the first one returned false.

Comment: This is not "the logical AND", it's a bitwise operator. And it may surprise you, because it does *not* work exactly like the logical `&&`.

Comment: It is the logic AND gate, why you say is not? and yes as I said is not the && or AND.
It will not surprise me because I actually know how it works.
Simple like checking this table and using the correct return type:

    1 & 1 = 1
    1 & 0 = 0
    0 & 1 = 0
    0 & 0 = 0

Comment: There's a distinction between the *logical* and the *bitwise* AND in PHP; this here is *not* the logical AND. And even if *you* know what its rules are, future readers may not.

Comment: This is "not" the logical operation asked by OP. Using a single & is a bitwise operation.

Comment: You are speaking about operators and I speaking about  gates,  in PHP both operators are an AND gate, but one is short circuited.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. If `$a == 1` and `$b == 2` then both `$a` and `$b` are not `FALSE` but `$a & $b == FALSE`.

Comment: @axiac your statement is wrong:
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
if ($a == 1 & $b == 2) is true,
if ($a & $b) is false

Comment: Both my expression an yours need some parentheses. I reformulate mine. Check it here: https://3v4l.org/MCKGA then read about PHP [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: Still wrong, you need to read everything, what I said is: If you need to check the result of both CONDITIONS.

Looks like you think that I comparing variables, but I didn't.
In your example, you are using two variables (bitwising) and that is not what I mean, I using two CONDITIONS that maybe be the result of a function call and they are BOOLEAN.

Comment: Regardless of your arguments, it's simply incorrect to say that a single ampersand (`&`) is a logical operator when in fact it is a bitwise operator. Gates (and your related assumption regarding short circuiting) are irrelevant: it does not matter HOW an engine that implements a high-level language specification works, as long as it comes up with the correct 'result' as specified (that's where the optimization-fun is for implementers). Without significant extra explanation you seriously confuse the target-audience who are on the 'level' where they ask if php has short circuit evaluation.

Comment: `Bitwise operators allow evaluation and manipulation of specific bits within an integer`. An integer-typed-*value* is NOT a boolean-typed-*value*. It doesn't matter if a value is referenced by a variable or constant or literal or ... A variable is NOT limited to integers as your last comment might lead others to believe. `FALSE !== 0` and `TRUE !== 1`. A bitwise operator requires it's LHS and RHS argument values to be silently casted to an integer (Type coercion) when needed (and possible) so that the mathematical (not logical) operation can do it's work.

Comment: still wrong, he is asking for something and I answered, It does not matter if correct or wrong to do it, he need to know how to avoid that, I answered, also I'm comparing Boolean and that works, period, and I using the & as a gate, yes In that case I using it >>AS<< logical operator, and your ARE OFF-TOPIC.

Comment: There's nothing off-topic about comments exclusively addressing an answer's content and/or it's comments. My comments exist mainly to help clarify both your answer and resulting discussion to the (future) target-audience of this question. No-one said it's 'wrong to do it', instead, others and myself have merely tried to patiently explain to you that the language (grammar/terminology) in your answer (the logical AND) does not convey the message (distributed across your comments) you are trying to give (which incidentally is not an answer to the question but a side note as you stated yourself).

Comment: my side note was more than clear, if he need to bypass the check of two conditions or booleans (not ints, not floats just bools), do like I wrote, anyway looks like several "easy trigger" down voted my comment (not sure why) people need to start reading more instead of down voting...

Comment: Stating both "conditions" of a bitwise operation are evaluated is a non-sequitur. Bitwise operations do not involve Boolean conditions, so of course shortcut circuit evaluation doesn't apply. This answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: wrong or not is not the point, you get both functions executed and the condition evaluated, all this drama for a side note :(