# Using isset($_REQUEST["p"]) or $_REQUEST["p"]

Tags: php

Sometime ago, I was in a internship, and I was working as a junior web-developer. While working and learning, I noticed that when  changing pages, instead of using `isset($_POST/GET/REQUEST["var"])` they just used `$_POST/GET/REQUEST["var"]`.

So, later I came home, and tried the same thing. What happens ? Every-time I come across a `if()` to verify that, I have to use `isset()`, otherwhise it gives me an error. But notice one thing, my url is this:

```
?p=sub_artigo&id=2
```

So, when I do the `if()` condition:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["p"])=="procurar" && $_REQUEST['cont']){
```

It doesn't show errors, but if I take of the `isset()`, it gives the usual error that I see in the forums and here.

So my question is, why doesn't show the error for the second variable ?

Note: p->string;id->int

Comment: [Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider reading **the SO Tour**. it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/php-short-circuit-evaluation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have `error_reporting` turned down, which is nice because it means you can do things like

```
if ($_POST['whatever']) { ... }
```

instead of

```
if (isset($_POST['whatever'])) { ... }
```

but it also stops you from seeing other possibly pertinent errors.

this setting is found in the `php.ini` file under the variable `error_reporting`.

More information on the ini file can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php

also, `isset($_REQUEST["p"])=="procurar"` while sytactically correct, is never going to return true, because `isset()` returns a boolean value.

what you want is `isset($_REQUEST['p']) && $_REQUEST['p'] == 'procurar'`

Comment: Yeah, lack of attention on that isset() from my behalf, darn it.

So it's the error_reporting..interesting. 
So in your opinion, which is more practical and secure ?

$_POST["var"] or isset($_POST["var"]) ?

Comment: using `isset()` is definitely the way to go. also check out `empty()` it checks the opposite.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much castits, much appreciated.

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 6):

RTM: http://php.net/isset

isset() returns a boolean TRUE/FALSE. It will **NEVER** return a string, so this statement

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["p"])=="procurar" && $_REQUEST['cont']){
```

can NEVER succeed, because isset() will never EVER be equal to `procurar`, so the `['cont']` check will never be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

When the first statement is false, PHP does not bother triyng the rest of the if statement.

I always use the following check on every $_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET key:

```
function ifSet($key) {   
    return (isset($_REQUEST[$key]) && $_REQUEST[$key])?$_REQUEST[$key]:'';
}
```

This will never give you any warnings, even if error_reporting is set to E_ALL.

The 'isset' checks if the $key is set and after that it checks if $key has a value.

Comment: You can extend this function with clean($_REQUEST[$key]) as output, where clean is your personal function for filtering input data. The combination of this I always use on every input variable.