# Quickest PHP equivalent of javascript `var a = var1||var2||var3;` expression

Tags: javascript, php, ternary-operator

Firstly is there a name for this expression ?

Javascript

```
var value = false || 0 || '' || !1 || 'string' || 'wont get this far';
```

`value` equals `string` (string) aka the fifth option

PHP

```
$value = false || 0 || '' || !1 || 'string' || 'wont get this far';
```

`$value` equals `true` (bool)

Am I right in thinking the correct way to achieve the same result as JavaScript is by nesting ternary operators? What is the best solution ?

Comment: It is `true` only..Test `echo true;`

Comment: You might wanna check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/does-php-have-short-circuit-evaluation) out.

Comment: In JS they’re called short-circuit evaluation

Comment: `<?php
$value = false || 0 || '' || true || 'wont get this far';
echo $value===true?'true':$value;
?>`

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen thanks Knowing the correct terminology helps a lot.

Comment: @Xufox  thanks Knowing the correct terminology helps a lot

Comment: You should use `var_dump($value)` to see it's type.

Comment: A better example would cause less confusion here... like `false || 'string'`, where the result is a string instead of the (for PHP programmers) expected `true`.

Comment: @deceze ive updated my example thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The equivalent operator in PHP is `?:`, which is the [ternary operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) without the middle part:

```
$value = false ?: 0 ?: '' ?: !1 ?: 'string' ?: 'wont get this far';
```

`$a ?: $b` is shorthand for `$a ? $a : $b`.

Comment: I think the question is not about ternary operator. But OP confusedly called ternary operator instead of short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: In Javascript `||` returns *one of its operands*, not a boolean. The equivalent way to do that in PHP is `?:`. Question answered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was assuming something else.

Comment: OP did not get confused, OP merely suggested using a ternary to achieve the result.

Comment: Just realized.. and deleted my answer to support this answer.

Comment: You can now in PHP 7 use the null coalesce operator `??`. If used carefully, it can make you code more robust against null pointer exceptions.

You can do things like:

`$desperateValue = $a->b->c ?? $a->b["d"]->f ?? $foo["snafu"]->bar ?? $x ?? 'no luck';`

This will return the first of these expression that will return a non null value (evaluated from left to right). The biggest advantage of this is that it evaluate nested properties and array keys and values without throwing any error. If something is not found, than the result will be null and it will move to the next expression.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using  PHP 5.3 or higher see [deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36451021/2273611).

Other wise you could use nested regular ternary operators.

```
$value = ( false ? false : ( 0 ? 0 : ( '' ? '' : ( !1 ? !1 : ( 'string' ? 'string' : ( 'wont get this far' ? 'wont get this far' : null ))))));
```

Wow thats ugly.

You could use an array of values instead;

```
$array = array(false,0,'',!1,'string','wont get this far'));
```

Now create a function which iterates over the array and returns the first true value.

```
function array_short_circuit_eval($vars = array()){
    foreach ($vars as $var)if($var)return $var;return null;
}

$value = array_short_circuit_eval($array);

echo $value; // string
```

Comment: `$value = current(array_filter(array(false, 0, ...)))` – I hope nobody needs to use this, but here it is...

Answer (score 1):

This test `false || 0 || '' || !1 || true || 'wont get this far'` will return a boolean value. It will return `true` if any of the values is `true`, that's how the `OR` works. It's not a ternary expression, which applies the first valid value to the receiving variable.

It returns `1` to PHP because you didn't cast the expression as a boolean.

You could do this to make the expression return a boolean value instead of an integer into your PHP variable:

```
$value = (bool)(false || 0 || '' || !1 || true || 'wont get this far');`
```

The return will be `true`.

Comment: *"`.. || ..` will return a boolean value..."*, *"You could do this to make the expression return a boolean value..."* – Which is it? Does `||` return a boolean or doesn't it?

Comment: It does return a boolean, but not directly into a variable, no in PHP. I don't get the two downvotes, but alrighty

Comment: Wut? Either it returns a boolean or it doesn't. There's no difference whether you assign the return value into a variable or not. A value is a value. The boolean return value of `||` won't get any more boolean by casting it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approche with 'or' and '=' operators.

example:

in Javascript:

```
$value = false || 0 || !1 || 'woow, i am selected';
```

in Php:

```
$value = false or $value = 0 or $value = !1 or $value = 'woow, i am selected';
```

This is possible because in Php 'or' operator has lower precedence order then '=' (assignment).

Comment: @NicoHaase  Its not a duplicated answer, this answer is using the combination of operators (or, =) and provides a correct result.