# Is the "and" keyword the same as if(TRUE) in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Inside a model class of Laravel 5 I came across the following code which I am not sure what it means.

```
$query = User::query();

\Request::input('name') and $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . \Request::input('name') . '%');
\Request::input('email') and $query->where('email', 'like', '%' . \Request::input('email') . '%');

return $query->paginate(15);
```

Is it the same as the following code?

```
if (\Request::input('name')) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . \Request::input('name') . '%');
}

if (\Request::input('email')) {
    $query->where('email', 'like', '%' . \Request::input('email') . '%');
}
```

Comment: _"Is it the same as the following code?"_ Yes and the latter is more readable. The former is using short-circuit evaluation

Comment: Yes............

Comment: IMHO the first example is just bad style and should not be used.

Comment: @Phil This question is not a real duplicate of the linked question, as it more belongs to `if` statements. I know what you mean, but this is confusing for newbies ...

Comment: @eisbehr it doesn't have to be exactly the same. There's examples in the answers on that question that answer this one. It also links to articles on short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: There's a lot of online code in tutorials that does things like `mysqli_connect... or die()` the principle is the same. `or` and `and` are basically the same as `||` and `&&` but just have a different precedence (which in your example doesn't even come into play)

Comment: I agree -- this question is closely related to [Does PHP have short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/does-php-have-short-circuit-evaluation?noredirect=1&lq=1), but there's enough difference for it not to be a duplicate.

Comment: To address the question in the title, "X and Y" is **not** the same as "true".

Answer (score 3):

It's [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). The PHP `&&` and `and` operators are the same for the most part (except for precedence, which we can ignore here). All boolean operators work with short-circuit evaluation; i.e. `0 and 1` can never be `true` because `0` is *falsey*, so PHP doesn't even need to evaluate the second operand `1`. Pretty much all languages do this.

Here this is used as a shorthand `if`. If `\Request::input('name')` is truthy, the second operand `$query->...` will be evaluated, otherwise it'll be skipped.

This is stylistically questionable and hardly endorsed, not least because it spawns questions like this. You should just write a traditional `if`, it's easier to comprehend and there's no shortage of lines you need to preserve.