# Checking if variable exist and if it has a certain value in one line

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have always thought that if I want to check if a variable exists and has a certain value I have to use two `if` conditions:

```
if(isset($x)){
    if($x->age==5){}
}
```

But I realized its also possible to do it in one line this way:

```
if(isset($x) && ($x->age==5)){}
```

Can someone tell me why the second variation will not result in an error if `$x` is null. Given that `$x` is null and doesn't have the property `age`? Would it be trying to access a property that doesn't exist?

```
$x=null;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does PHP have short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694733/does-php-have-short-circuit-evaluation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$x` is null, `isset($x)` is false. Then, because of the logical operator "AND" (`&&`), the condition cannot be fully validated, so, the test is stopped here and `($x->age==5)` is not executed.

For a shorter code, as of PHP 8.0.1, you can use the [NullSafe Operator (`?->`)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator)

```
if ($x?->age == 5) { }
```